# PHP Turn this into a while or for loop?

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop, switch-statement

```
if(count($crumbs) >= 1)
    print("<a href=\"$startpage?dir=$crumbs[0]\" >".$crumbs[0]."</a> >> ");
if(count($crumbs) >= 2)
    print("<a href=\"$startpage?dir=$crumbs[0]/$crumbs[1]\" >".$crumbs[1]."</a> >> ");
if(count($crumbs) >= 3)
    print("<a href=\"$startpage?dir=$crumbs[0]/$crumbs[1]/$crumbs[2]\" >".$crumbs[2]."</a> >> ");
```

I have this code and I was wondering if there was some way I could turn it into a while or for loop so I don't have to keep making more and more if statements.

Comment: Just go with switch-case

Answer (score 3):

You can use `switch ...case` instead of multiple `if`. but you can't convert it into `for` or `while` loop, it will be too messy.

Comment: If the printing order was reversed you could use a switch(with fall through), but as it is a switch won't work

Answer (score 1):

with small fixes, this should work

```
$count = count($crumbs);
for ($i = 0; $i < count && $i < 3; $i++){

    $echoes = "<a href=\"$startpage?dir=";
    $arg = array();
    for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++){
        $args[] = $crumbs[$j];
    }

    $echoes .= implode('/', $args)."\">".$crumbs[$i]."</a> >> ";

}

echo $echoes;
```

Comment: you have a forward slash after $crumbs[$j]